# Xcode wont let me drag and drop buttons

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, drag-and-drop

I have been working with xcode for about 3 days. Everything worked just fine up until today. I was dragging buttons and labels to where my code is located just fine as shown in the first screenshot but for some reason, it wont let me drag and drop items from the second view control . Im sure its an easy fix but i cant seem to find a soulution on my own. I have researched it and people have had the same issue but that was due to their code. Mine is fresh since I created a new project and it does not like my second viewcontrol.

[image: Second Screen that isnt letting me drag and drop]

[image: first screen working just fine]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use one view controller for multiple views. For all views you have, you need your own custom controller class. That means, that you need to create a new view controller class(cmd + N), select Cocoa Touch class, name it, and in the identity inspector of your second view(in the Storyboard), select your new view controller class. Then you can drag and drop labels, buttons, etc, when on the right size of the assistant editor, your second view controller class is opened.

Comment: I made a new class . Im confused with the identity inspector part. I know where it is but I guess i still need help with the part where xcode recognizes my second viewcontroller class with the second screen on my main storyboard

Comment: identity inspector is in the 3d tab, when you select your view. There are several different fields: "class", "module", "storyboard ID" etc. You need the first one. Just start typing the name of your view controller class, and xcode will help you. But make sure, that you created UIViewController class, not an NSObject

Answer (score 0):

Create an another class ExampleViewController and call it in identity inspector.
More about identity inspector: [apple lesson](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html)

Comment: This helped me alot as well. I got it working now thanks to you all. It was weird as when i was identifying the custom class " viewcontroller1" (the new class) it wouldnt just pop up. Thats why i was getting confused. Got it working now. Thank you